# Are there compelling reasons not to use Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, jvm

I'm developing a LoB application in Java after a long absence from the platform (having spent the last 8 years or so entrenched in Fortran, C, a smidgin of C++ and latterly .Net).

Java, the language, is not much changed from how I remember it. I like it's strengths and I can work around its weaknesses - the platform has grown and deciding upon the myriad of different frameworks which appear to do much the same thing as one another is a different story; but that can wait for another day - all-in-all I'm comfortable with Java. However, over the last couple of weeks I've become enamoured with Groovy, and purely from a selfish point of view: but not just because it makes development against the JVM a more succinct and entertaining (and, well, "groovy") proposition than Java (the language).

What strikes me most about Groovy is its inherent maintainability. We all (I hope!) strive to write well documented, easy to understand code. However, sometimes the languages we use themselves defeat us. An example: in 2001 I wrote a library in C to translate EDIFACT EDI messages into ANSI X12 messages. This is not a particularly complicated process, if slightly involved, and I thought at the time I had documented the code properly - and I probably had - but some six years later when I revisited the project (and after becoming acclimatised to C#) I found myself lost in so much C boilerplate (mallocs, pointers, etc. etc.) that it took three days of thoughtful analysis before I finally understood what I'd been doing six years previously.

This evening I've written about 2000 lines of Java (it is the day of rest, after all!). I've documented as best as I know how, but, but, of those 2000 lines of Java a significant proportion is Java boiler plate.

This is where I see Groovy and other dynamic languages winning through - maintainability and later comprehension. Groovy lets you concentrate on your intent without getting bogged down on the platform specific implementation; it's almost, but not quite, self documenting. I see this as being a huge boon to me when I revisit my current project (which I'll port to Groovy asap) in several years time and to my successors who will inherit it and carry on the good work.

So, are there any reasons not to use Groovy?

Comment: +1 for a good question, even if you are rambling a bit :)

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand wanting to use a java base language that has dynamic types. Whole point of using a c type language is type safety. hurts my head!

Comment: @WolfmanDragon  If that were really the "whole point" then fine... but Java is more than just a C-type language, and the toolsets that have evolved around the JVM are useful, even if you don't want/need strong type-checking.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two reasons I can think of not to use Groovy (or Jython, or JRuby):

- If you really, truly need performance
- If you will miss static type checking

Those are both big ifs. Performance is probably less of a factor in most apps than people think, and static type checking is a religious issue.  That said, one strength of all of these languages is their ability to mix and match with native Java code. Best of both worlds and all that.

Since I'm not responsible for your business, I say "Go for it".

Comment: Compile-time type checking is now available with Groovy 2.x using annotations.

Answer (score 13):

If you use Groovy, you're basically throwing away useful information about types. This leaves your code "groovy": nice and concise.

```
Bird b
```

becomes

```
def b
```

Plus you get to play with all the meta-class stuff and dynamic method calls which are a torture in Java.

However -- and **yes** I have tried IntelliJ, Netbeans and Eclipse extensively -- serious automatic refactoring is not possible in Groovy. It's not IntelliJ's fault: the type information **just isn't there.** Developers will say, "but if you have unit tests for every single code path (hmmmm), then you can refactor more easily." But don't believe the hype: adding more code (unit tests) will add to the safety of massive refactoring, but they don't make the work easier. Now you have to hand fix the original code **and** the unit tests.

So this means that you **don't refactor as often in Groovy,** especially when a project is mature. While your code will be concise and easy to read, it will not be as brilliant as code that has been automatically refactored daily, hourly and weekly.

When you realize that a **concept** represented by a class in Java is no longer necessary, you can just delete it. In Eclipse or Netbeans or whatever, your project hierarchy lights up like a Christmas tree, telling you exactly what you've screwed up with this change. `def thing` tells the compiler (and therefore your IDE) nothing about how a variable will be used, whether the method exists, etc. And IDEs can only do so much guessing.

In the end, Java code is filled with "boilerplate," but it's been kneaded into its final form after many refactorings. And to me, that's the only way to get high-quality, readable code for future programmers, including when those future programmers are you-in-the-future.

Comment: take a minute to analyse your refactorings. It is mostly changes in the boilerplate code. E.g. new Field in the Domain -> changes in more than 5 class files. If I compare refactorings in Grails and Java Projects, then in Java projects I had to refactor 10 times often.

Comment: It's a good point. On the other hand, "mostly" is the important word here. Refactoring is sometimes how we reflect new understandings in code, develop new type hierarchies, etc. Refactoring is the process of taking code that used to make sense and bring it back in line.

Comment: I realize this is old, but I find I refactor in Groovy a lot more - because our code files are so much more readable that code smells show better. Less LOC means it's easier to see anti-patterns. 

Also, our team is more likely to use healthy patterns in the first place, rather than taking shortcuts to avoid boilerplate.  E.g., using List<SimpleInnerClass> instead of Lists<List<String>>. Small classes in Groovy are easy due to properties, but hard to read in Java - and therefore opaque - due to boilerplate.

I suspect compilers have also gotten better with Groovy in the past 5 years.

Comment: Good points... now experiencing this same beginning-of-life with Swift. Ugh

Comment: @EthelEvans If boilerplate for simple value types is killing you, I strongly recommend taking a look at the [Immutables library](http://immutables.github.io/), which is a much less invasive addition to Java to solve value type creation (what I find is 80% of the boilerplate problem). Of course, that does require support from your toolchain, and may not address your concerns if you have lots of mutable value types (I consider it a smell when I see it in my own code and value the difficulty in creating mutable types, but the ideal feature set is different for every developer).

Comment: I couldn't have put it better myself. As someone coming from Java, this answer completely describes my complaints about programming in Groovy (and other dynamic languages). I might as well be programming without an IDE. Not only that, but Groovy isn't even consistent. You CAN static type if you want, so the code becomes a big mishmash of static and dynamic typing. Refactoring is awful in any dynamic language. Unit tests are written for a reason. And that reason is NOT to do static type checking that a compiler can do better.

Comment: @Mike point's even more relevant to Swift. Xcode cannot refactor very well at all, and anything less than perfect is basically useless. I kinda miss Java circa 2002 ;)!

Answer (score 9):

Two reasons why [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) might be a compelling alternative to Groovy:

- Performance on par with Java
- Static typing without clutter

Comment: +1. Scala is pretty awesome. I didn't mention it because he seemed focused on dynamic languages.

Comment: My experience with Scala is that it is still pretty chatty with types -- and you end up having to use a *lot* of parens because of funky (and often surprising) precedence rules.

Comment: @Fischer: Mind giving an example?

Comment: Groovy has caught up with scala performance as of Groovy 2.0 (especially on Java 7)

Comment: @fikovnik here's one that I just found (though comparing to Java) http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-20-performance-compared.  Note that gains will be seen when you use CompileStatic

Answer (score 7):

One of the biggest things you lose when you use dynamic languages, especially in a large codebase is the ability to use an IDE to re-factor.  Languages that allow dynamically adding code to objects simply can't be parsed by today's IDEs to allow the kind of easy refactoring methods you can get from Eclipse, etc. for Java, C++, etc.

It's not really a case of "Dynamic languages are better than Static".  Use what's best for you.  The really cool thing about Groovy in particular is you can mix and match Java and Groovy in the same project, and it all runs on the VM.  Yes, Scala is another example.

Comment: There's a surprising amount of improvement in that arena, particularly if you're using a framework (like Grails).

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest issue is lack of IDE support compared to java, however the plugins for Eclipse and Netbeans are getting better all the time. Also, if I remember correctly Groovy does not support anonymous inner classes if you really need them for some reason. I would personally choose Groovy anytime though.

Comment: while it doesnt support anonymous inner classes, groovy does have a replacement for them that some argue may be better - anonymous lambdas , or closures as its called in groovy.

Comment: @Chii it does support anonymous inner classes now.

Comment: this is a bit of an old response.  STS is an AWESOME IDE for Groovy and Grails.